# Incorrect output form in Openui5

Tags: sapui5

I have this form on an XML view.
I simply want to add a form of two formElements:

```
<f:Form id="FormChange354"
            minWidth="1024"
            maxContainerCols="2"
            editable="true">
            <f:layout>
              <f:ResponsiveGridLayout
                labelSpanL="3"
                labelSpanM="3"
                emptySpanL="4"
                emptySpanM="4"
                columnsL="1"
                columnsM="1" />
            </f:layout>
            <f:formContainers>
              <f:FormContainer>
                <f:formElements>

                  <f:FormElement label="Codice Articolo">
                    <f:fields>
                      <Text xmlns="sap.m" id="idCodArt" text="codice_articolo_prova"/>
                    </f:fields>
                  </f:FormElement>

                  <f:FormElement label="Codice Nome Doganale">
                    <f:fields>
                      <Text xmlns="sap.m" id="idCodNomDog" text="codice_doganale_prova"/>
                    </f:fields>
                  </f:FormElement>




                </f:formElements>
              </f:FormContainer>
            </f:formContainers>
          </f:Form>
```

Why is the output this...? :/

[image: the output]

Is this a problem of the first part of form declaration?

Comment: The form looks ok at first sight... Maybe your viewport is too small (minWidth=1024) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug!
Until it is corrected, use an Input and set editable="false".
See here: http://jsbin.com/bokavisu/1/edit

Comment: if I include it into a grid the result is good!
But If i use TextArea (not a Text) how i can resolve a problem?